# Read lines from doc using python and compare to a set of words

Tags: python, visual-studio-2012, cpython

There's a doc ex.doc with contents like

```
    The doctor set a due date of August 17th.
```

Now i want to read this line by line using **CPython 2.7** and divide them into arrays of words like , as follow:

```
    ['The','doctor','set','a','due','date','of','August','17th','.']
```

If we can get special characters and numbers separate it will be better .
Then i would like to compare **each words** to existing set of data like

```
    ['January'..........}
```

To know which month */ ( profession like i can search doctor from list of professions )* the given line is talking about .

Please try to help by easier and cleaner code.

Here's my progress :

```
   with open("ex.doc") as file:
       my_list = file.readlines()
       my_list = [x.strip() for x in my_list]
   mt = ['Jan','Feb']
   mtPresent=0
   for lines in my_list:
       for words in lines:
           if words in mt:
               mtPresent=1
       if mtPresent == 1:
            print(rows) 
       #if line contains jan or feb then only line will be displayed
       mtPresent = 0
```

We should be able to compare word ':' among the list of ['is',':'].
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

So, your questions contains two problems. The first is splitting a sentence into its words. There is a number of resources out there how best to do *tokenization*, as it is called, but for now something like this will do:

```
import re

text = "The doctor set a due date of August 17th."
words = set(re.findall(r'\w+', text))
```

Because you only care about which words occur and not their order, I chose to use the `set` datatype, since finding elements in it is faster and more convenient in python.

Now, given a set of months and professions that you want to find, you can simply do the following:

```
months = {"August", "February"}        # or whatever you need 
professions = {"doctor", "carpenter"}  # same here

month = months.intersection(words)
profession = professions.intersection(words)
```

which will print

```
print(month)
>> {'August'}
print(profession)
>> {'doctor'}
```

If you have questions regarding regexes, sets, or anyhting else, please feel free to ask.

Edit:

If the .docx file you extract the text from is a simple, unformatted libne based file, this code should be able to convert it into a list of strings to better work with:

```
from docx import Document

text_lines = []
for line in Document("demo.docx").paragraphs:
    text_lines.append(line.text)
```

The docx library can be installed to python 2.7 to 3.4 with

```
pip install python-docx
```

If you have any say in the project, I would advice not to store information that is supposed to be machine readable in something as unhandy as docx. Plain .txt is, in my experience, preferable.

Comment: I need the position like for sentence , Name of the Doctor : Arne ,i want to know the name of the doctor occurring after ":" . Or like "Arne is name of the doctor " so the word before " is " is the name of the doctor .So i need to search / compare the words and also need their position .If " : " position is 2nd then help me printing contents at 3 and later than 3 . 2 and 3 are index .

Comment: And with your code , def presence(row):
    import re
    text = "Doctor : 1"
    words = list(re.findall(r'\w+', text))
    d = {"Doctor", "carpenter"}          
    sc = {":", ","}   
    dash = d.intersection(words)
    sp = sc.intersection(words)
    print(dash)
    print(sp)

presence("okay") # the ":" is not displayed

Comment: Where can you find the name of the doctor? Please include in your initial question what *exactly* is all your input and desired output.

Comment: Input : Name of the doctor is John .
Output : in the list of doctors John will be added 
Input : Carpenter Name : John
Output : in the lists of carpenters John will be added .
I want to know the loaction at which the intersection is occurring , if there's ":" in sentence then later that symbol will be the name of doctor or carpenter if that's "is" samething also .

Comment: please help doing this with docx file .Because i got update that i have to do this with docx files , no more with doc .

Comment: Now your post essentially consists of three different questions. You might consider opening different Posts for them where you adequately describe the problem, and what you did so far to solve it. I added a section in my answer for the docx part. I still don't get how you obtain the doctor's name.

Comment: i just want know the loaction/index of doctor in the sentence :" The doctor set a due date of August 17th. "that is 2 .

Comment: while using  
from docx import Document

text_lines = []
for line in Document("demo.docx").paragraphs:
    text_lines.append(line.text)

the list has prefix "u" in starting of every element

how to solve that ?

Comment: By slicing it off. I can't walk you through the code like this though, I think revisiting the basics of python will serve you better then asking in the comments for the next step: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/ That is not what the comments are intended for.